# AWS Lambda python library

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I am looking for an SDK that includes the Selenium library for AWS Lambda. If SDKs are shared as open source and can be added to our own Lambda function's Layer with their ARN, could you please share the ARN of this SDK?

I added the Selenium library for Python3.10 as a .zip file to the Layer, but I keep getting a 'no module named' error. I want to see if I get the same error with other SDKs.

```
import json
from selenium import webdriver

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

I followed these steps step by step:
Creating a Lambda Function:

Sign in to the AWS Management Console and navigate to the Lambda service.
Click the "Create function" button.
Select the "Author from scratch" option to create a new function.
Provide a function name and choose the runtime (e.g., Python 3.10).
Specify the places where the function will execute (e.g., VPC) (optional).
Click the "Create function" button to create the Lambda function.

Adding Required Libraries to the Function:

Create or edit the main code file of your function (e.g., lambda_function.py).
Open the terminal in the directory where your function's file is located.
Use the pip command to install the necessary libraries and place them in the function's file directory (e.g., pip install pandas -t .).
Create a .zip archive of your function's file and library files.

Adding the Library File to a Layer:

Go to the AWS Management Console and navigate to the Lambda service.
Click the "Layers" option in the left menu.
Click the "Create layer" button.
Fill in the layer name and description fields.
Click the "Upload" button to select and upload the .zip archive to the layer.
Click the "Create" button to create the layer.

Adding the Layer to the Lambda Function:

Go to the edit page of the Lambda Function.
Click the "Add layer" button.
On the "Add layer" page, select the layer you created and specify its version.
Save the changes.

```
import json
import pandas

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

I can't install this library either, it keeps giving the same error. I get the same error for every library

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/opt')
```

This line of code solved the error. After adding the libraries to the layer, I can import them without error.